# cursor not getting placed where it is clicked in textarea

Tags: javafx-2

we are developing desktop application using javafx in which cursor is not getting displayed where  it is clicked in the textbox instead it displaying at the end of the text. what we have done that first we deselecting the selected text by using caret position. what happening is once we select the text area it gets selected/focused and the cursor go by default end of the text, by the second click we are getting  the cursor where we clicked. These text area is placed in Vbox.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to place cursor at the end of the text.

```
private void placeCursor()  {

       textarea.positionCaret( textarea.getText().length());
}
```

If you want to place cursor at the end of the currrent line.

```
private void placeCursor() {

    int location =  textarea.getCaretPosition();
    String[] x =  textarea.getText().split("\n");
    int wLength = 0;
    for (String s : x) {
        wLength = wLength + s.length();
        if ((location - 1) < wLength) {
            break;
        }
        wLength = wLength + 1;
    }
    textarea.positionCaret(wLength);

}
```